# instead of puting # in href atribute of link,is there is another option to get the same working?

Tags: html, href

Since we do not have any page to link it to, we put # as the link in our examples.

It should be a real URL to a specific page.

```
<a href="#"> Click Here </a>
```

> I wanted to know,  is there is another option to get the same working?

Comment: @LaljiTadhani - Unfortunately, You have not got the point of my question. It is not similar, it is a different one.

Comment: You have to change the Question

Comment: Question is same I corrected English mistakes.

Comment: `Why do we put a # in the href attribute of the link?` vs `instead of puting # in href atribute of link,is there is another option to get the same working?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes people want to make an explicit link to the top of the page.

More usually, they are binding JavaScript to a click event on the element and don't actually want to link anywhere at all … in which case they should use a button and not a link.